# Is there a way to stack up the cells of a table side by side?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

What i mean by this is that cell1 would be top left. Cell2 would be top right. Cell 3 would be below cell 1, cell 4 would be below cell 2 etc..

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't... that pretty much what a table does? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` does not support this out-of-the-box.  You can fake it, but you might also want to try using something like [`AQGridView`](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

Comment: As Dave said, this might helpful

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableView` only allows for one column, so it's really more of a stack or list than a table. To do what you are talking about you will need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` either in Interface Builder or code that "fakes" columns through layout, but you will only ever have one cell per row.

From the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A table view in the UIKit framework is
>   limited to a single column because it
>   is designed for a device with a small
>   screen.